# express.js (passport local) + vue.js, req.isAuthenticated() always give false

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, express-session, passport-local

Please help me.. 3 days I can not solve this problem. I'm trying to get user data after this log in.
log in works succssesfull
and data in serializeUser are correct too
but deserializeUser never been used
and req.isAuthenticated() always is false
req is undefined

logs..

serializeUser.id 6482e523f95162e64e947db0

and request to endpoint gives {"noa":"no auth"}

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session'); // Add this line
const passport = require('passport');

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/vuejs', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error);
  });

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

// Middleware to parse JSON request bodies
app.use(express.json());

// Add the express-session middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'd4503c6f001d4e08cf2vs3vasr304e08c009',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

// Register the user routes
app.use('/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/password', userRoutes);

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

```
//passport.js
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/User');
const session = require('express-session'); // Add this line
// Configure the local strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Serialize and deserialize user instances
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser.id', user.id);
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log('deserializeUser was called');
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log('deserializeUser', user);
        console.log('deserializeUser err', err);
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

module.exports = passport;
```

```
// endpoint rout backend 
router.post('/checkAdmin', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const isAdmin = req.user && req.user.email === 'admin@gmail.com';
    res.json({ isAdmin, test }); // Include the isAdmin field in the response

  }
  else {
    const noa = 'no auth';
    res.json({ noa});
  }
});
```

```
// rout vue 

{
    path: '/admin', 
    name: 'admin',
    component: AdminPanel,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      adminEmail: 'admin.com' // Specify the admin email address
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/checkAdmin', { withCredentials: true }, {
        headers: {

          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      })
  .then(response => {
    // Handle the response
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle the error
    console.error(error);
  });
    }
  }
```

I checked it, but I have this code

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'd4503c6f001d4e08cf2vs3vasr304e08c009',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

this too

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser.id', user.id);
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log('deserializeUser was called');
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log('deserializeUser', user);
        console.log('deserializeUser err', err);
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```